# Can't run git bash in windows-terminal

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

I try to run git bash in windows terminal, so i followed tutoriels but when i add to the profile settings of windows terminal

```
"profiles" :
[
 {
   "commandline" : "\"%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\bin\\bash.exe\" --login -i -l",
   "guid" : "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000012345}",
   "icon" : "%PROGRAMFILES%\\git\\mingw64\\share\\git\\git-for-windows.ico",
   "name" : "Git Bash",
 },
```

i get

```
[erreur 0x80070002 lors du lancement de `"%PROGRAMFILES%\git\bin\bash.exe" --login -i -l']
```

Also i can't access to bash.exe in my PROGRAMFILES, this is why it's not working, so i added the path to git-bash.exe but that open my git bash terminal in an other window. I want to open it in a new tab

Do someone had the same issue